# Displaying node fields in a view

Tags: 7, views, entities

I have a content type called Snippet. Snippet will have one image field and unlimited text fields.

I want to output fields in Views as:

- image field (image.png)
- text field (Text1)
- text field (Text2)
- text field (Text3)
- text field (Text4)

The image field is always first, and the different text fields follow it. I want to put this into a slideshow format with fade transitions.

Right now, the image field keeps reproducing itself after every text field.

Do you have any idea? Do I need to use grouping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should use [Views Slideshow](http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) to do this.

On Drupal 7, add 2 more text fields in your content type; then add them to the view using *Content: [your text field name]*.